# Xamarin.Mac: Launch another application with arguments in the sandbox

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.mac

I implemented launch at login for my application using this tutorial:
https://blog.timschroeder.net/2012/07/03/the-launch-at-login-sandbox-project/

Basically you would need to implement a Helper app that will be registered to start at login and the Helper will launch your application.

The problem is that I would like to launch my application hidden and for that I need to pass it one argument. Unfortunately I didn't find any way to do that.

I found these methods to launch an App:

```
//Works to launch the app but no way to pass arg
var app = SBApplication.FromBundleIdentifier(PackageId);
app?.Activate();

//Same issue here
NSWorkspace.SharedWorkspace.OpenFile("/Applications/HelloWorld.app")

//If you run the code bellow outside of the sandbox it works fine.
//Inside of the sandbox it just launches the app but without args
var aTask = NSTask.LaunchFromPath("/usr/bin/open", 
                new string[] { "-a","HelloWorld.app", "--args", "--hidden" });
aTask.Launch();
```